# How to Code a TOC Title and Divider Beneath Which Facilitates Possible Height Adjustments

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, tocloft, vertical-spacing, height

I have a centered TOC title and linear divider beneath which I would like to simultaneously raise or lower in the document, maintaining the blank vertical space between the two.

I don't know if I have optimally coded the two, but please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries} % To Center TOC title.
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}  % To Center TOC title.

\newcommand{\divider}
{%
  \begin{center} \vspace*{-55pt}
  \rule{1.75in}{.2mm}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect\divider\hfil\par}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{\bf 1.} An entry in the TOC.}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace*{0pt}THE TOC}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

I would like to be able to the raise or lower the height of the TOC title and associated divider beneath.

Now, without the divider, `\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace*{-20pt}THE TOC}` would raise the title 20pts.

I thought perhaps that simultaneously changing `\vspace*{-55pt}` in the `\divider` portion of the code to `\vsoace*{-75pt}` along with `\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace*{-20pt}THE TOC}` would accomplish this for me, but it doesn't. Moreover, the command `\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace*{-20pt}THE TOC}` by itself doesn't seem to effect the title; but rather surprisingly, the divider.

QUESTION: How might I alter the above code to produce a centered TOC title and specified divider beneath which facilitates the raising or the lowering their heights with either a `vspace*` command or something comparatively similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option (without using `tocloft`)

You define the title of the `ToC`, its format and the vertical  spacing of the rule. The length of the rule will automatically be set to the width of the formatted `ToC` title  using `\widthof{<text>}`.

If you choose 0pt as vertical spacing as the rule, the rule will be placed on the baseline of the table of contents title.

`\ToCabove` helps to move vertically the ToC title and its rule.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins

%******************************************  Definitions
\newcommand{\ToCname}{THE TOC} % Define ToC title
\newcommand{\ToCformat}{\Huge\bfseries} % Define the  format of ToC title <<<<<
\newcommand{\ToCrulesep}{2ex}% set the  vertical space  separation<<<<<
\newlength{\ToCabove}   
\setlength{\ToCabove}{-5ex}% set space above the ToC title
%****************************************** 

\usepackage{calc}% for widthof <<<< 

\newsavebox{\ToCtitle}  
\savebox{\ToCtitle}{% build box with ToC title + rule
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\centering% 
\ToCformat\ToCname\par%
\vspace*{\dimexpr\ToCrulesep-\baselineskip\relax} 
\rule{\widthof{\ToCformat\ToCname}}{.2mm} % set rule length equal to width of formatted ToC title
}}
\newcommand{\InsertToCtitle}{\vspace*{\ToCabove}\usebox{\ToCtitle}} 
\renewcommand\contentsname{\InsertToCtitle} % use the saved box     
%******************************************         
    
\begin{document}        
    \LARGE
        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{\bf 1.} An entry in the TOC.}
        
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this fine answer.

Comment: @mlchristians I updated the answer several times. Be sure that you are using the last version.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it when I get back.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. It seems now that the vertical space between the divider line and the first entry remains constant no matter the value substituted into `\setlength{\ToCabove}{-5ex}`---which is, indeed, preferable.  By the way, would you know of a simple way to specify a value for that gap? I didn't see it specified in the code, so I am thinking that the gap length between the divider and the first entry as shown is some default value.

Comment: @mlchristians It is `\newcommand{\ToCrulesep}{2ex}% set the  vertical space  separation<<<<<` Rename the command to something more meaningful to you.

Comment: I tried that; but, when I change the value of 2 to something else, it affects the space between the  title and the divider, not the space between the divider and the first entry.

Comment: @mlchristians Please verify that you are running the published answer. "THE TOC" should be nailed to the page.

Comment: Yes, I copied it directly from this site and when I change, say 2 to 12, it produces a very large gap between the title and the divider beneath. I am compiling with `lualatex` if that makes a difference.

Comment: The TOC title indeed remains "nailed" to the page; it's just the divider that drops accordingly.

Comment: @mlchristians There are `ex` units around 10pt each,  so 12ex is around 120pt or more. Change to mm or pt if you want. The advantage of using ex units (the height of and x character at the current font family and size) is that the length scale when you change the font.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly good that one can specify the gap between the title and  divider beneath. I was hoping that there exists a command similar to `\ToCrulesep` to then specify the gap between that divider and the first entry of the TOC. Perhaps I'll post it as a question sometime. Thank you.

Comment: @mlchristians To do that add  `\vspace*{<some length>}`  after `\rule{\widthof{ ...`

Comment: Thank you! That works very, very nicely.